# When you blow through your nose while holding it closed to "depop" you ears, why do you sometimes feel it in your eyes?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, human-eye, nose

After your ears have "popped", for example on a flight, I heard you are supposed to hold your nostrils closed and blow through your nose to readjust the pressure to the normal level. Why do you sometimes feel a pop in the corner of your eye when you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sinuses connect the ear, nose and throat as well as the tear ducts of the eye. The pressure created when holding your nose and blowing is transferred to any area it can get to; in this case, the eyes and ears.